# Can we control when the Bluetooth access prompt is shown programmatically (like location)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios13

I asked a question recently on how to access the callback from the new Bluetooth access prompt in iOS 13 regarding the new description - *NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription*. I'm not sure I even saw a Bluetooth access prompt unless Bluetooth was off with the old description - *NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription*.

Registering the prompt callback involved implementing an instance of *CBCentralManager* and registering the `UpdatedState` event handler.

Now I'm wondering - is there a way to determine **when** the prompt is shown?

If we create a default Xamarin.Forms/Xamarin.iOS application and add the following to it's *Info.plist* file-

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
<!--The app communicates with BLE peripherals using the Core Bluetooth framework.-->
<string>bluetooth-central</string>
<!--The app shares data using the Core Bluetooth framework.-->
<string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
</array>

<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>App would like to use bluetooth.</string>
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>App would like to use bluetooth.</string>
```

It would appear the new Bluetooth prompt is **ALWAYS** shown on application start. Can we as developers address this like location?

Here's what I mean by "*like location*". Similarly if location access is added to the plist file, like below, then the prompt occurs on application start. **HOWEVER** this prompt's timing to be shown to the user can be manipulated!

Simply instantiate the LocationManager instance when we want the prompt to be shown -

```
Manager = new LocationManager();
Manager.LocationUpdated += HandleLocationChanged;
```

The problem we are facing is that even without initializing any Bluetooth related instances/classes/implementations/etc the app **ALWAYS** prompts for Bluetooth first. So-

**Can we control when the Bluetooth access prompt is shown programmatically (like location)?**

(In case anyone be curious- to access callback for Location prompt register the `CLLocationManager.AuthorizationChanged` event)

And similarly these are the plist entries we currently have for location

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>App would like to access location.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>App would like to access location.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>App would like to access location.</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source code of `CBCentralManager`. You will find that it has a constructor

```
public CBCentralManager(ICBCentralManagerDelegate centralDelegate, DispatchQueue queue, CBCentralInitOptions options);
```

So you can set the property  **ShowPowerAlert** as true when init the `CBCentralManager`

```
CBCentralManager manager = new CBCentralManager(new xxxDelegate(),null,new CBCentralInitOptions() { ShowPowerAlert=true});
```

When `CentralManager` is initialized, an Alert will pop up if bluetooth is not turned on .

Comment: The prompt we are seeing is for Bluetooth access. Once acknowledged (allowed/or not) it never shows again and the event "UpdatedState" is how we capture and handle the state whatever it may be. Specifically the usage description pop-ups defined in the Info.plist.

Comment: This is because of privacy design in iOS . The alert will only appear again if user close the permission in system setting page .

Comment: Our mistake. We had an instance of CBCentralManager being instantiated elsewhere that was resulting in showing the prompt. Thanks!